# Ubuntu Phone (BQ Aquaris E4.5) with mouse - How to make mouse coursor visible?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, mouse, cursor, phone

When I connect a USB mouse to my **BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition**, I can do different actions, with a non visible mouse cursor.

Is it possible to make the mouse cursor visible?
I installed a terminal and tried this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

like I found here: 
http://itsfoss.com/invisible-mouse-cursor-ubuntu-1310/

But that doesn’t work, because this settings doesn't exist on the phone.
Is there a solution to make the mouse cursor visible?

Comment: I guess Gnome is X-server only, but the Ubuntu Touch UI uses the mir display manager. Maybe it has something like that, but probably not.

Answer (score 0):

I asked similar question in:
[Ubuntu Phone lack of cursor for OTG/USB mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680816/ubuntu-phone-lack-of-cursor-for-otg-usb-mouse)

mhall119 replied:
'It's not available yet, but is being actively worked on. Mir 0.16 has just been released, and I think the mouse cursor fix is targeted for 0.17.'

Hope that helps out.