# Ubuntu Phone lack of cursor for OTG/USB mouse

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, mouse, phone, cursor

My Ubuntu phone just arrived today. It is 'Aquaris E5 HD Ubuntu Edition'.
As any Linux enthusiast would I updated phone to 15.04, installed 'Terminal' and wanted to play about with it.

Connected my micro USB to USB OTB cable and connected mouse/keyboard USB receiver. 
UI changed from I would describe 'phone version' to 'desktop/tablet Unity'?
Regardlesss of UI changes i tried to use mouse which did not work as expected as it had:

-No mouse cursor.

Tested keyboard and that seemed to work relatively ok, but since many of UI elements still require mouse selection keyboard itself is not usable without mouse.

Now I read few posts without replies that this is the problem for some people but nothing official or a fix that I could find.

So in short:
How do I get cursor on my Ubuntu phone and/or when will this be fixed?.

Answer (score 1):

It's not available yet, but is being actively worked on. Mir 0.16 has just been released, and I think the mouse cursor fix is targeted for 0.17.